# Testing abstract class throws InstantiationException

Tags: java, exception, junit

It's the first time I've written JUnit tests and I came across the following problem. I have to write the tests for an abstract class and I was told to do it this way: 
http://marcovaltas.com/2011/09/23/abstract-class-testing-using-junit.html

However, when I try to run the first test I get an `InstantiationException` like this:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

Here's the test I'm running:

```
/**
 * Test of setNumber method, of class BaseSudoku.
 */
@Test
public void testSetNumber_3args() {
    System.out.println("setNumber");

    BaseSudoku b = getObject(9);
    boolean expResult = false;
    boolean result = b.setNumber(0, -7, 7);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);            
}
```

Note that Base Sudoku is an Abstract Class and HyperSudoku is a child.

I have implemented the following abstract method in BaseSudokuTest:

```
protected abstract BaseSudoku getObject(int size);
```

And here's the implementation in `HyperSudokuTest` that extends the `BaseSudokuTest`:

```
@Override
protected BaseSudoku getObject(int size) {  //I need size for other implementations 
    return new HyperSudoku();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace please?

Comment: testSetNumber_3args caused an ERROR: java.lang.InstantiationException

java.lang.InstantiationException at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)

This is all I get!

Comment: I would ask you to post a minimal test case we can run that would reproduce this. Add the `BaseSudoku` and HyperSudoku` classes.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be your `HyperSudoku` and `BaseSudoku` after all. It seems to be your test class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I added the code you asked for.

Comment: @Mureinik I'm trying to get the full stacktrace, too.

Comment: Can you please post your test class ? The probem seems to be there.

Comment: Thank you @Patrick for your interest! ;) Problem's solved!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've stated that `BaseSudokuTest` has an `abstract` method and is therefore `abstract` itself.

Assuming you are running your tests through `BaseSudokuTest`, Junit uses reflection to create an instance of your test class. You cannot instantiate abstract classes, whether directly or through reflection.

Move your abstract method to some other class. Your JUnit test class cannot be `abstract`.

Or rather run your `HyperSudokuTest` class. It will have inherited the `@Test` methods from `BaseSudokuTest`.

Comment: JUnit ignores abstract test classes, unless of course you click on the class in an IDE and try to run it explicitly...  Having just tried that, it gives exactly the exception in the question.

Comment: @Nick I'm assuming that's what OP did. I'll modify my answer if we get more details.

Comment: I specifically clicked on the class, in order to run the test.
However, I made the Test class abstract, because I saw it in the tutorial I posted, which was sent to me by my professor. There it seems to be working!

Comment: @sofia In your professor's example, they make an `abstract` base class with `@Test` annotated methods and a child class with `@Test` annotated methods. They then run the non-abstract child class with JUnit, not the `abstract` class.

Comment: @Sofia you need to run `HyperSudokuTest`, which is presumably the class that implements the `getObject` method.

Comment: @Nick Holt (And Sotirios Delimanolis) thank you both for your replies. I ran the test through the HyperSudokuTest class and it worked! I was trying to run the BaseSudokuTest! I was wrong! Thank you both bery much!

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar issue, which was caused by adding my abstract test class to a TestSuite:

```
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class AllTests {
    public static TestSuite suite(){
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTestSuite(SessionTest.class); // Abstract class
        suite.addTestSuite(CourseSessionTest.class); // Extends SessionTest        
        return suite;
    }
}
```

Taking SessionTest.class out of my TestSuite fixed my problem because I was attempting to instantiate an abstract class by adding it to the suite (which was where the errors were coming from) and the CourseSessionTest was calling all of the methods in it anyway.